# Protobuf-net bug - serializing fixed array that is set to null

Tags: protobuf-net

I'm using protobuf-net library to serialize some objects. I have a field

```
[ProtoMember(3, DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize, IsPacked = true)]
ushort[] foo;
```

When I set it to say `ushort[] { 3 }` and then serialize the whole object and read it back it's fine. Then when I set foo to either an empty array or null and serialize and read it back again, it's not erased. I end up getting the array with 3 in it. To make sure it's not some file system problem I changed other properties and did the roundtrip and they all behaved as expected.

Does anyone know if this is a bug in the implementation or a feature?

Comment: which version of protobuf-net are you using, and do you have a sample I can look at to see exactly what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't *entirely* clear without a reproducible example, but IMO the most likely answer here is that you are overwriting an output stream (such as a file) without truncating it. Because the protobuf spec does not include terminators (etc) for the ***root*** object, it reads to the end of the file. If you then overwrite with less data, any contents not truncated are garbage.

Now, if the change means the garbage at the end doesn't parse as protobuf, [you'll get an exception, like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152978/using-protobuf-net-i-suddenly-got-an-exception-about-an-unknown-wire-type). However, if the data is still valid (because, for example `foo` is the last item in the stream) then it'll just read it and process it. In particular, setting a collection results in that item *not being written*, hence why setting it to null still leaves a valid stream (if it is the final field to be serialized).

If you aren't already doing so, ensure you trim your outputs (2 simple ways of doing this are shown in the post linked above).

If this is unrelated, then I apologise - but without further information / a reproducible example I have to use a little guesswork ;p

Comment: Yep, that was it. I didn't know about the truncation issue. Thanks.

Comment: @jz87 yeah it is an inbuilt issue when dealing with (and overwriting) streams; it isn't specific to protobuf-net