# protobuf-net and repeated field

Tags: c#, java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Is it right to use List as counterpart of the repeated field in protobuf? I'm trying this and always got exception:

Invalid wire-type; this usually means you have over-written a file without truncating or setting the length; see [Using Protobuf-net, I suddenly got an exception about an unknown wire-type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2152978/23354)

The whole buffer is (the first msg, next which arrive are appended to this):
 9 8 5 26 5 24 238 98 32 1

java protobuf file:

```
package XXX;

option java_package = "XXX";
option java_outer_classname = "Protos";

option optimize_for = SPEED;

message V3DDelta {
  optional int32 bid = 1;
  optional int32 bidSize = 2;
  optional int32 ask = 3;
  optional int32 askSize = 4;
}

message Request {
  optional int32 type = 1;
  optional string request = 2;
}

message Response {
  optional int32 type = 1;
  optional string response = 2;
  repeated V3DDelta v3dDelta = 3;
}
```

and protbuf-net classes:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class V3DDelta {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public double bid { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int bidSize { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public double ask { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public int askSize { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Request {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Type { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Rq { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Response {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Type { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Rsp { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public List<V3DDelta> v3dDelta { get; set; }
    public Response() {
        v3dDelta = new List<V3DDelta>();
    }
}
```

I tried V3DDelta[] but result is the same.
Reading message:

```
Response rsp = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Response>(rcvstream, PrefixStyle.Base128);
```

and in java message is send using writeDelimitedTo.
Buffer in c# is exactly the same as in java.
When there was na v3dDelta field everything works as expected.

Comment: got it all working... that was fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, either `List<T>` or an array (`T[]`) will work for `repeated`. Incidentally, there is a tool for generating protobuf-net classes from a .proto definition.

<s>You are trying to read it "with length prefix", however: 9 **is not valid** as a varint prefix (`9`, as a field header, means "field 1, fixed 64-bit data", however: in this context it should be a *varint*).</s>

Actually, **none** of your data is compatible with `9` as a field header, since you don't have any 64-bit values in your definition as field `1`. You *do* have a `double` as field `3`, which would do the job nicely - however, that would be `73` as a field header.

I would tell you what the sequence 9,8,5,... represents, however - we would have:

```
9 : field 1, fixed 64-bit
    8 5 26 5 24 238 98 32 <== payload for above
1 : field 0, fixed 64-bit
    ^^ not *really* valid, but fields <= 0 generally mean "stop" - but
       frankly this is not a clean/defined/expected exit condition
```

So again: please check your data. That doesn't look like a protobuf stream, or at least not one that matches your schema.

---

Edit: it occurred that maybe the java writeDelimitedTo includes **just** the length, without a header) making it technically not a consistent protobuf file, but... meh), so let's investigate that:

```
int len = ProtoReader.DirectReadVarintInt32(ms);
```

which gives us `9`, and we have `9` bytes left, so looking good...

```
8 : Field 1, varint
  5 = payload of above
26 : Field 3, length-delimited
  5 = length of payload
   24 238 98 32 1 = payload of ^^^
      24 : Field 3, varint
          238, 98 = payload of ^^^ = 12654
      32 : Field 4, varint
          1 = payload of ^^^ = 1
```

This now looks like it should parse... investigating why it isn't...

---

Edit 2: after a bit more debugging, *part* of this is because you (sorry to say) borked the `V3DDelta` properties. You defined them as `int32` in the proto (and field 3 is a varint in the data), but you implemented them as `double`... and `double` and `int32` are not friends.

So:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class V3DDelta
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int bid { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int bidSize { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public int ask { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public int askSize { get; set; }
}
```

and then the following works fine:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    int len = ProtoReader.DirectReadVarintInt32(ms);
    var resp = (Response)model.Deserialize(ms, null, typeof(Response), len);

    Assert.AreEqual(5, resp.Type);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, resp.v3dDelta.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(12654, resp.v3dDelta[0].ask);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, resp.v3dDelta[0].askSize);
}
```

Technically, I *could* make protobuf-net accept a `varint` for a `double` value, but this is highly indicative of a schema that doesn't really match, so I think the correct thing is to change the type in this case.

Comment: Yes, it was it, now it works as it should. I just forgot change field type after changint it in proto. Thank you and sorry for taking time.