# Invalid wire-type when using Authenticate filter on DTO

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, servicestack

> Invalid wire-type; this usually means you have over-written a file without truncating or setting the length; see [Using Protobuf-net, I suddenly got an exception about an unknown wire-type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2152978/23354)

I just added the `[Authenticate()]` filter to my DTO here:

```
[RestService("/tr/file/")]
[RestService("/tr/file/{Path*}")]
[DataContract]
[Authenticate()]
public class File
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

And I get that error.  I've read the suggested link without any hint on how it affects authentication.  My first thought is that the Username/Password fields don't have an `(Order=N)`.  I'm using the `ProtoBufServiceClient` which should be obvious by the error and tag.

Anyone encountered this before and what should I try as a fix?

Here's my Get() service method:

```
public override object OnGet(TRServiceLib.Types.File request)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Path))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("File path cannot be empty.");

    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(this.Config.RootDirectory, Utils.GetSafePath(request.Path));

    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
    if (!file.Exists)
        throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException(request.Path);

    return new FileResponse()
    {
        Name = file.Name,
        Contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path)
    };
}
```

PS: Everything works as intended without the `[Authenticate()]` filter attribute.

Comment: I don't recognise this at all, and protobuf-net certainly doesn't care about that extra attribute. Without meaning to pass the buck, I think this is a ServiceStack thing. First question though: do both client and server know about the (same) authentication rules?

Comment: @MarcGravell They both use the same service library, if that is what you mean.  IE, they have the same DTO classes, etc.

Comment: A little birdie tells me you already submitted a patch for this ;p

Comment: not quite yet.  I did get the Ordering attributes added to the Auth DTO's, but I'm not 100% sure that was the problem.  My brain is ready to explode, so I'm putting this aside for a bit.