# Using Protobuf-net, I get an exception about an unknown wire-type with List<Subclassable>

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, protobuf-net

I've started to convert our Unity/iOS game to save state with Protobuf-net. It looked like things were working OK, until I added this instance variable to `GameState`

```
[ProtoMember(10)]
public List<Unit> fUnits;
```

Unit is

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(21, typeof(ArtilleryUnit))]
[ProtoInclude(22, typeof(CavalryArtilleryUnit))]
[ProtoInclude(23, typeof(CavalryUnit))]
[ProtoInclude(24, typeof(InfantryUnit))]
[Serializable]
public class Unit : IActionHandler
```

This is the first subclass I've serialized. I'm testing my code by deserializing right after writing

```
using (Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(readText);
    memoryStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    WBTSSerializer deserializer = new WBTSSerializer();

    testState = new GameState();
    deserializer.Deserialize(memoryStream, testState, typeof(GameState));
}
```

and I get

```
ProtoBuf.ProtoException: Invalid wire-type; this usually means you have over-written a file without truncating or setting the length; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2152978/23354
  at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.SkipField () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at WBTSSerializer.Read (wbts.Unit , ProtoBuf.ProtoReader ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at WBTSSerializer.Read (wbts.GameState , ProtoBuf.ProtoReader ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at WBTSSerializer.Deserialize (Int32 , System.Object , ProtoBuf.ProtoReader ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore (ProtoBuf.ProtoReader reader, System.Type type, System.Object value, Boolean noAutoCreate) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream source, System.Object value, System.Type type, ProtoBuf.SerializationContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream source, System.Object value, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at wbts.Game.SaveGame (System.String filename) [0x000c1] in /Users/david/Shenandoah/WBTS/wbts/wbts/Game.cs:620
```

Needless to say, I've checked for overwriting (it's a brand new file). And, if I take out the `ProtoMember(10)`, it won't throw.

If I take out the `ProtoInclude` lines, I get an error about the subclasses. And, if I take out `ProtoMember` within `Unit`, it still throws.

If it matters, I am currently just running this from Xamarin (on Mac OS X — I'm an iOS developer). But that's just for ease of testing, I have managed to hit Protobuf-net with enough sticks to make it run on an iPad.

Answer (score 2):

My eye is drawn immediately to:

```
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(readText);
```

Protobuf data **is not text**, and is not UTF-8 (although strings *inside* protobuf data are UTF-8, by coincidence) - therefore "decoding" it (wrong word, really) via `UTF8` will guarantee you corrupt data. The preferred way to deal with protobuf data is as binary - for example, a `byte[]` - much like you would with image data etc. However, if you are required to store or transport it in a text form, then `Convert.ToBase64String` and `Convert.FromBase64String` are appropriate mechanisms to translate between text and binary. Please see the first section of [How many ways can you mess up IO?](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html) for more information.

Comment: That's almost certainly it, a .NET-ignorant copy-paste from our XML serialization. Unfortunately, I started getting other errors as soon as I used proper byte[] handling (including Mono itself crashing) and then I forgot the steps I went through to get an iOS-able DLL. So for now I'm back to .NET's XML serialization.