# Getting ProtoBuf.ProtoException using OsmSharp in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, openstreetmap, protobuf-net

I am trying to test a sample project called Android.Routing.Offline from [OsmSharp.Samples](https://github.com/OsmSharp/OsmSharp.Samples) in Github.

After two taps on the screen (the first one gets just the GeoCoordinate)  I get a ProtoBuf.ProtoException in the Router.cs

```
private static IBasicRouterDataSource<CHEdgeData> _graph;

    public static void Initialize()
        {
            var routingSerializer = new CHEdgeDataDataSourceSerializer();
            _graph = routingSerializer.Deserialize(
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(@"Android.Routing.Offline.kempen-big.contracted.mobile.routing"));
        }

    public static Route Calculate(GeoCoordinate from, GeoCoordinate to)
            {
                try
                {
                    lock(_graph)
                    {
                        var router = Router.CreateCHFrom(_graph, new CHRouter(), new OsmRoutingInterpreter());

                        // The exception happens here below
                        var fromResolved = router.Resolve(Vehicle.Car, from); 
                        var toResolved = router.Resolve(Vehicle.Car, to);

                        if(fromResolved != null && toResolved !=null)
                        {
                            return router.Calculate(Vehicle.Car, fromResolved, toResolved);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    OsmSharp.Logging.Log.TraceEvent("Router", OsmSharp.Logging.TraceEventType.Critical, "Unhandled exception occured: {0}", ex.ToString());
                }
                return null;
            }
```

And the exception:

```
  > {ProtoBuf.ProtoException: Invalid wire-type; this usually means you
    > have over-written a file without truncating or setting the length; see
    > http://stackoverflow.com/q/2152978/23354  at
    > ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadSingle () ...
```

I didnt overwrite the file (kempen-big.contracted.mobile.routing) just added it as a linked file in the project. Any ideas how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first thing to try is to check that the contents of the `Stream` you are reading (via `GetManifestResourceStream`) contains exactly the contents you are expecting, and not some wrapper or otherwise-corrupt mess. If you have some checksum algorithm you can run: great! Checking just the `.Length` would be a great start. Otherwise, you could cheat (just for the purposes of validating the contents) by getting the hex:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(ms);
    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(
        ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
    // dump this string, and compare it to the same output run on the
    // oringal file; they should be identical
}
```

Note that this duplicates the contents in-memory, purely so we can get a `byte[]` (oversized) to get the hex from - it isn't intended for "real" code, but until you are sure that the contents are correct, all other bets are off. I strongly suspect that you'll find that the contents are *not* identical to the contents in the original file. Note that I'm also implicitly assuming that the original file *works fine* in terms of deserialization. If the *original* file doesn't work: again, all bets are off.

Comment: What do you mean by saying original file? I just downloaded the file from the github and I put a link of this file in the project .. even if I put the actual file in the project the same exception happens.

Comment: @Stam I mean the file that contains protobuf data. If that file doesn't parse in a simple console exe (not doing anything fancy like manifest streams), then there is a problem.