# how to serialize / deserialize List<class object> with protobuf?

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I want to serialize `List<ArchiveData>` but it nearly always fail. Protobuff throw following exception:

> Invalid wire-type; this usually means you have over-written a file
>   without truncating or setting the length; see
>   [Using Protobuf-net, I suddenly got an exception about an unknown wire-type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2152978/23354)

I have read the post but still can not find a solution. How can i serialize and deserialize this?

My Class and Struct:

```
[Serializable, ProtoContract(Name = @"Archive"), ProtoInclude(1, typeof(List<ArchiveData>))]
public partial class Archive : IExtensible
{
    [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true, OverwriteList = true, Name = @"data", DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
    public List<ArchiveData> data { get; set; }

    public Archive()
    {
        data = new List<ArchiveForm.ArchiveData>();
    }

    private IExtension extensionObject;
    IExtension IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
    {
        return Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing);
    }
}

public struct ArchiveData
{
    [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, OverwriteList = true, Name = @"sourcefolder", DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
    public string sourcefolder { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = false, OverwriteList = true, Name = @"destinationfolder", DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
    public string destinationfolder { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3, IsRequired = false, OverwriteList = true, Name = @"period", DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue((int)0)]
    public int period { get; set; }

    public ArchiveData(string sfolder = "", string dfolder = "", int priod = 0)
    {
        sourcefolder = sfolder;
        destinationfolder = dfolder;
        period = priod;
    }
}
```

I serialize that with following method:

```
public static void Refresh(ref Archive arc)
{
    if (File.Exists(probuffile))
    {
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(probuffile))
        {
            arc = Serializer.Deserialize<Archive>(fs);
        }
    }
}
```

And i deserialize that with following method:

```
public static void Update(Archive arc)
{
    using (var fs = File.Create(probuffile))
    {
        Serializer.Serialize<Archive>(fs, arc);
        fs.SetLength(fs.Position);
    }
}
```

And i use it:

```
Archive archive = new Archive();
//Add some ArchiveData.
Refresh(ref archive);
```

------------------------------Edit------------------------------

This section has been added for more information. When I use SerializeWithLengthPrefix / DeserializeWithLengthPrefix function like following code, it work properly every time for the first class that i use the Deserialize function. But it return null for the second class that i use the Deserialize function.

```
[Serializable, ProtoContract(Name = @"OptionData")]
public class OptionData : IExtensible
{
    [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, OverwriteList = true, Name = @"StartWithWindows", DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool StartWithWindows { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = false, OverwriteList = true, Name = @"AutoBackup", DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool AutoBackup { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3, IsRequired = false, OverwriteList = true, Name = @"Speed", DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize)]
    [DefaultValue((int)0)]
    public int Speed { get; set; }

    private IExtension extensionObject;
    IExtension IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
    {
        return Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing);
    }
}

public static void Update(OptionData op)
{
    using (var fs = File.Create(probuffile))
    {
        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(fs, op, PrefixStyle.Base128, 3);
    }
}

public static void Update(Archive arc)
{
    using (var fs = File.Create(probuffile))
    {
        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix<Archive>(fs, arc, PrefixStyle.Base128, 2);
    }
}

public static void Refresh(ref OptionData op)
{
    if (File.Exists(probuffile))
    {
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(probuffile))
        {
            op = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<OptionData>(fs, PrefixStyle.Base128, 3);
        }
    }
}

public static void Refresh(ref Archive arc)
{
    if (File.Exists(probuffile))
    {
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(probuffile))
        {
            arc = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Archive>(fs, PrefixStyle.Base128, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see any `List<object>` in the question - can I assume that the real issue here is actually just "(de)serializing an object, am getting the wire-type error" ?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I forgot to write class.

Comment: Re the edit: are they in the same file? or different files? if you want to read two successive things from the same file, you need to read them successively on a single `File.OpenRead` session. Otherwise, every time you call `File.OpenRead` it will be back at the start of the file and will be reading the wrong data. You don't show how `Update` and `Refresh` are used, so I can't be 100% sure. Again, the best thing to do - like in my answer - is to post some **fully runnable** code (with a `Main()` method etc) that demonstrates the problem actually happening.

Comment: I give up to try serialize/deserialize two diffrent classes. I gather all in one and i works fine. If it slows down when the file size grows, i will try separate the class to two different classes. Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd be happy to help, but I'm struggling to get it to fail. You say "but it nearly always fail", but the following runnable console exer works fine and writes a large range of data of various sizes:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var random = new Random(12345);
        // start with 100
        var archive = CreateData(random, 100);
        Update(archive);
        Refresh(ref archive);

        // make it bigger
        archive = CreateData(random, 200);
        Update(archive);
        Refresh(ref archive);

        // make it smaller
        archive = CreateData(random, 50);
        Update(archive);
        Refresh(ref archive);

        // go wild
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            archive = CreateData(random, random.Next(0, 500));
            Update(archive);
            Refresh(ref archive);
        }

    }
    static Archive CreateData(Random random, int dataCount)
    {
        var archive = new Archive();
        var data = archive.data;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++)
        {
            data.Add(new ArchiveData
            {
                period = random.Next(10000),
                sourcefolder = CreateString(random, 50),
                destinationfolder = CreateString(random, 50)
            });
        }
        return archive;
    }

    private static unsafe string CreateString(Random random, int maxLength)
    {
        const string Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        int len = random.Next(maxLength + 1);
        char* chars = stackalloc char[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = Alphabet[random.Next(Alphabet.Length)];
        }
        return new string(chars, 0, len);
    }

    static string probuffile = "my.bin";
    public static void Refresh(ref Archive arc)
    {
        if (File.Exists(probuffile))
        {
            using (var fs = File.OpenRead(probuffile))
            {
                arc = Serializer.Deserialize<Archive>(fs);
                Console.WriteLine("Read: {0} items, {1} bytes", arc.data.Count, fs.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Update(Archive arc)
    {
        using (var fs = File.Create(probuffile))
        {
            Serializer.Serialize<Archive>(fs, arc);
            fs.SetLength(fs.Position);
            Console.WriteLine("Wrote: {0} items, {1} bytes", arc.data.Count, fs.Length);
        }
    }
}

[Serializable, ProtoContract(Name = @"Archive"), ProtoInclude(1, typeof(List<ArchiveData>))]
public partial class Archive : IExtensible
{
    [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true, OverwriteList = true, Name = @"data", DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
    public List<ArchiveData> data { get; set; }

    public Archive()
    {
        data = new List<ArchiveData>();
    }

    private IExtension extensionObject;
    IExtension IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
    {
        return Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing);
    }
}
[ProtoContract]
public struct ArchiveData
{
    [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, OverwriteList = true, Name = @"sourcefolder", DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
    public string sourcefolder { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = false, OverwriteList = true, Name = @"destinationfolder", DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
    public string destinationfolder { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3, IsRequired = false, OverwriteList = true, Name = @"period", DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue((int)0)]
    public int period { get; set; }

    public ArchiveData(string sfolder = "", string dfolder = "", int priod = 0)
    {
        sourcefolder = sfolder;
        destinationfolder = dfolder;
        period = priod;
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that whatever the difference is between your real code and the example above : is also the cause of the problem. If you help find what is different, I'd be more than happy to help however I reasonably can.

As a minor note: you don't actually need to set the length when using `Create`, since that is explicitly "throw away any existing data". The main time you need to worry about the length is when people use `OpenWrite` to write over an existing file, and then write *less* data than was already there. But there isn't a *problem* with explicitly setting the length after `Create`

Comment: I finally realise when fails.(I have another serializable class called OptionData). 1-)When i serialize/deserialize just OptionData, It works properly. 2-)When i serialize/deserialize just Archive, It works properly. But 3-)when i deserialize Archive while both OptionData and Archive was serialized, Archive is fails and OptionData works properly.

Comment: @BurakKocaman if you want me to look into that, I'm going to need some code. As a guess: are you serializing them back-to-back in the same stream (i.e. two calls to `Serialize`)? If so, you'll need to use the `*WithLengthPrefix` methods. However, a simpler fix for that would be to create a single root object that has the two items as members 1/2, i.e. `[ProtoContract] class MyRoot { [ProtoMember(1)] public Archive Archive {get;set;} [ProtoMember(2)] public OptionData Options {get;set;} }`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried to use WithLengthPrefix and I thought I should look for a different solution when it didn't work. But after your answer, i'm sure i used it wrong. I will try to use WithLengthPrefix until it work properly :D Thanks again.

Comment: @BurakKocaman if you want me to fix what you have, I can do that - but I'd need to see code that fails