# Deserializing ByteString into an object using C# Google.Protobuf

Tags: c#, deserialization, protocol-buffers

So i have a gRPC message coming in from a different service (written in another programming language).
here is a mini version of this object (obviously the real one is generated by protobuf)

```
public class Message
{
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public Google.Protobuf.ByteString Msg { get; set; }
}
```

My issue is that the ByteString should be deserialized into another object (also defined in the protobuf file), but when i am trying to deserialize the Msg field i keep getting this error:

> Protocol message contained a tag with an invalid wire type.

and the stack trace

> at Google.Protobuf.UnknownFieldSet.MergeFieldFrom(CodedInputStream
>   input)    at
>   Google.Protobuf.UnknownFieldSet.MergeGroupFrom(CodedInputStream input)
>   at Google.Protobuf.CodedInputStream.ReadGroup(Int32 fieldNumber,
>   UnknownFieldSet set)    at
>   Google.Protobuf.UnknownFieldSet.MergeFieldFrom(CodedInputStream input)
>   at Google.Protobuf.UnknownFieldSet.MergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet
>   unknownFields, CodedInputStream input)    at
>   Messages.RecordingStatusChangeMessage.MergeFrom(CodedInputStream
>   input) in
>   C:\Users\iliaar\go\src\RecorderApp\testers\NewRecorderTester\Infra.AppDataManager\Model\Protos\Pubsub\messages.pb.cs:line
>   3259    at
>   ClusterRecordersModule.RecordersViewModel.OnNewMessage(Message
>   message) in
>   C:\Users\iliaar\go\src\RecorderApp\testers\NewRecorderTester\ClusterRecordersModule\ViewModels\RecordersViewModel.cs:line
>   154

I have tried calling several methods of the new object and all have failed
for example i have tried using an existing instance and merging like:

```
innerMessageObject.MergeFrom(message.Msg.CreateCodedInput());
```

or using the static parser like:

```
InnerMessageObject.Parser.ParseFrom(message.Msg.ToByteArray());
```

and all have failed with the same error and the stack trace ultimately converges to the same place in Google.Protobuf library.
my library version is 8.1.0 and I also tried downgrading all the way down to version 6

i would really appreciate some help.
Thank you

Edit: 
the innerMessage object is structured as follows:

```
public class InnerMessageObject
{
    public string ConfigID { get; set; }
    public bool Storage { get; set; }
    public bool Signal { get; set; }
    public string StorageTransition { get; set; }
    public string SignalTransition { get; set; }
}
```

also, convering to Hex result in the following (valid) output

```
63-6F-6E-66-69-67-5F-69-64-3A-20-37-32-30-62-66-65-34-39-2D-64-62-32-39-2D-34-35-38-33-2D-39-66-65-31-2D-65-30-32-30-37-33-32-37-39-37-39-34-0A-73-74-6F-72-61-67-65-3A-20-66-61-6C-73-65-0A-73-69-67-6E-61-6C-3A-20-66-61-6C-73-65-0A-73-74-6F-72-61-67-65-5F-74-72-61-6E-73-69-74-69-6F-6E-3A-20-22-32-30-32-30-2D-30-33-2D-30-33-54-31-32-3A-32-36-3A-34-31-2E-33-32-37-34-30-34-33-5A-22-0A-73-69-67-6E-61-6C-5F-74-72-61-6E-73-69-74-69-6F-6E-3A-20-22-32-30-32-30-2D-30-33-2D-30-33-54-31-32-3A-32-36-3A-34-31-2E-33-32-37-34-30-33-32-33-31-5A-22-0A
```

furthermore, coverting the bytearray into string results in a string representation of the object with the correct data

```
var ba = pubsubMessage.Msg.ToByteArray();
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ba);
```

> config_id: 720bfe49-db29-4583-9fe1-e02073279794
>   storage: false
>   signal: false
>   storage_transition: "2020-03-03T12:29:59.531473957Z"
>   signal_transition: "2020-03-03T12:29:59.531473589Z"

Comment: The real question here is: is the payload of `Msg` actually valid? I'm guessing it isn't, but to test this, get the payload contents as, say, hex: `var hex = BitConverter.ToString(message.Msg.ToByteArray())` (and write `hex` somewhere - to the console is fine), and then run that hex through [this handy decoder/validator](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode) - if the validator agrees that the data is invalid: **the data is invalid**, and the thing you need to do is fix where the data is coming from

Comment: i suppose the content is fine since deserializing it in the source service works fine. also the hex validator didnt specify any error

Comment: That's very odd, then; I don't know how sensitive your data/payload is here; are you able to perhaps share the payload and the schema of `InnerMessageObject`, so that we can help more? (context: I'm the author of that validator site; I understand the protocol very well)

Comment: yea sure, im editing the main question right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your payload **is not protobuf**. If we try it through [this validator](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode), we see:

> 63 = field 12, type StartGroup
>
> error: Invalid wire-type; this usually means you have over-written a file without truncating or setting the length; see [Using Protobuf-net, I suddenly got an exception about an unknown wire-type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2152978/23354)

so let's look at the first two bytes as if they are protobuf - the decoder tells us what 0x63 means; the next byte 0x6F should be a field header ("tag"); in binary this is 01101111, which would be "field 13, wire-type 7"; there **is no wire type 7 in protobuf**. So; the decoder is correct: the payload is not valid.

But not all is lost!

If we take a guess from all those 0x6* values that this might be ASCII or UTF8, and decode it as such, we get:

```
config_id: 720bfe49-db29-4583-9fe1-e02073279794
storage: false
signal: false
storage_transition: "2020-03-03T12:26:41.3274043Z"
signal_transition: "2020-03-03T12:26:41.327403231Z"
```

which appears to be your data in some crude line-based tokenized format. But: not protobuf.

Comment: i suppose you are right, the thing is the other service is written in golang, there i used proto.Marshal to serialize the object and when i deserialize it again in the go service it work fine. is there a chance there is anything to do with the language differences?

Comment: @Nitzanu no; whatever the golang is doing to build the payload, it *is not creating protobuf output*; if it was creating protobuf output, it would be protobuf no matter the language