# Protobuf-net deserialize string field to c# guid

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

In a simplified scenario, assume we have a custom c# type which contains a guid field and the corresponding proto type is,

```
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
  string guid_id = 2; // this is defined GUID in corresponding c# type
  repeated string names = 3;
  map<string, double> prices = 4;
}
```

When I try to deserialize this proto to c# type, I get exception stating 'Invalid wire-type' and a link to [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2152978/23354) which is not helpful to me. Is there a work around for this or am I overlooking something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protobuf-net has opinions on guids. Opinions that were forged back in the depth of time, and that I now regret, but which are hard to revert without breaking people. If I was writing this today with hindsight, yes: it would probably just serialize as a string. But: that isn't what it expects today!

Frankly I'd hack around it with a shadow property. So instead of

```cs
[ProtoMember(42)]
public Guid Foo {get;set;}
```

You could use:

```cs
public Guid Foo {get;set;}
[ProtoMember(42)]
private string FooSerialized {
    get => Foo.ToString(); // your choice of formatting
    set => Foo = Guid.Parse(value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In protobuf-net v3, this changes; there is now a concept called `CompatibilityLevel`, that works for this scenario; if a `Guid` member or containing type has `CompatibilityLevel` of 300 or more, then it is treated as a `string`. This topic is discussed in depth here: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/docs/compatibilitylevel.md