# protobuf-net: ProtoException in serializing and deserializing nullable enum with length prefix

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, protobuf-net

This code reproduces the problem:

```cs
Type Resolver(int fieldNumber)
{
    return typeof(ConsoleColor?);
}

var stream = new MemoryStream();
ConsoleColor? obj = ConsoleColor.Green;
Serializer.NonGeneric.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, obj, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);

stream.Position = 0;
Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128, Resolver, out var dd);
//EXCEPTION!!!
```

I am simply serializing a nullable enum value. But when I try to deserialize, I get below exception:

> ProtoBuf.ProtoException: Invalid wire-type; this usually means you have over-written a file without truncating or setting the length; see `https://stackoverflow.com/q/2152978/23354`'

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to fix or work around the issue? I am using version 2.4.6 of protobuf-net library. (Cannot move to 3.x because I am stuck with .Net Framework 4.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a `Nullable<T>` into an API that takes `object`, it is *boxed*, and the boxing rules for `Nullable<T>` are special: it boxes to *either* a regular `null`, or a box of `T`, not a box of `T?`; in other words: an `object` value **never** contains a nullable value-type. Because of this, from the library's perspective you sent a `ConsoleColor`, not a `ConsoleColor?`, so:

```cs
Type Resolver(int fieldNumber)
{
    return typeof(ConsoleColor);
}
```

As a side note, though: the resolver API is *very* specific and niche, and there are *usually* better ways to do things. If you can tell me what you're trying to *achieve*, I can probably offer more guidance.

(I'm trying to think whether there is *ever* a scenario where the resolver could meaningfully return a `typeof(Nullable<T>)` for some `T` - we *could* perhaps have the library just unwrap the nullable itself, or raise a more meaningful message)

Comment: Thank Marc! Yes I do see the issue now. Actually I have a RPC library which automatically generates the serialiser for method arguments. For example, during a call to `int Sum(int a, int b)`, library serialises the arguments `a` (with field number 1), and `b` (with field number 2) and sends it over wire. On the receiving end, it does the reverse to get the arguments and invokes the function call. I got stuck when I used `SomeEnum?` as argument.

Comment: But I still don't understand why `int?` works but `SomeEnum?` doesn't?